# Return Original value when can't find string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column D is result of LOOKUP from Column C

```
   A       B       C          D
1 1234   1234567   Person1   ASKXXXXXXXX
2 3692   8465837   Person2   AFTXXXX
3 4789   7846199   Person3   AHY
```

To replace `X`s in D with B if there are 8 of them,
and to replace `X`s in D with A if there are 4X's, I use this formula

```
=IF(SEARCH("XXXXXXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXXXXXX",$B$2),IF(SEARCH("XXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXX",$A$2),""))
```

But, its not gonna work when no "XXXXXXXX" and "XXXX" (Row 4)

Comment: What about `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("XXXXXXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXXXXXX",$B$2),IF(SEARCH("XXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXX",$A$2),"")),D2)` ?

Comment: Thank you. When I didn't sleep several days looking at Excel I tend to miss simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFERROR(value, value_if_error)` :

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("XXXXXXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXXXXXX",$‌​B$2),IF(SEARCH("XXXX‌​",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,‌​"XXXX",$A$2),"")),D2‌​)
```